# Android - how to parse json with object at index

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm beginner, so I don't know how to parse json, when the json data doesn't have a key

This is my Json data

```
[
            {
                "products_id":10052,
                "products_name":"\u0e08\u0e35\u0e19 : The Haven Sword and Dragon Sabre - \u0e01\u0e23\u0e30\u0e1a\u0e35\u0e48\u0e1f\u0e49\u0e32\u0e14\u0e32\u0e1a\u0e21\u0e31\u0e07\u0e01\u0e23 1994 **\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e15\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e08\u0e44\u0e21\u0e48\u0e15\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e40\u0e19\u0e37\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e15\u0e49\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e2d\u0e20\u0e31\u0e22**",
                "products_description":"<P>\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e41\u0e2a\u0e14\u0e07:<BR>- \u0e2b\u0e21\u0e48\u0e32\u0e08\u0e34\u0e48\u0e07\u0e40\u0e17\u0e32 (Steven Ma Jing Tao) \u0e23\u0e31\u0e1a\u0e1a\u0e17 \u0e40\u0e15\u0e35\u0e22\u0e1a\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e01\u0e35\u0e49 \u0e01\u0e31\u0e1a...",
                "products_date_available":"0",
                "products_image":"100909-TheHavenSword.jpg",
                "addDate":"2010-10-24 09:59:58"
            },
            {
                "products_id":10117,
                "products_name":"Nogizaka Haruka no Himitsu - \u0e04\u0e27\u0e32\u0e21\u0e25\u0e31\u0e1a\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e22\u0e31\u0e22\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13\u0e2b\u0e19\u0e39 Season 1 + 2 (\u0e1a\u0e23\u0e23\u0e22\u0e32\u0e22\u0e44\u0e17\u0e22) **\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e2d\u0e20\u0e31\u0e22\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e15\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e20\u0e32\u0e1e\u0e44\u0e21\u0e48\u0e15\u0e23\u0e07\u0e01\u0e31\u0e1a\u0e40\u0e2a\u0e35\u0e22\u0e07\u0e40\u0e19\u0e37\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e08\u0e32\u0e01\u0e15\u0e49\u0e19\u0e09\u0e1a\u0e31\u0e1a**",
                "products_description":"<P>Nogizaka Haruka \u0e19\u0e32\u0e07\u0e40\u0e2d\u0e01\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e40\u0e23\u0e37\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e19\u0e35\u0e49 \u0e40\u0e1b\u0e47\u0e19\u0e44\u0e2d\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e2b\u0e19\u0e36\u0e48\u0e07\u0e40\u0e14\u0e35\u0e22\u0e27\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e42\u0e23\u0e07\u0e40\u0e23\u0e35\u0e22\u0e19\u0e19\u0e35...",
                "products_date_available":"0",
                "products_image":"10-NogizakaHarukaNoHimitsu.jpg",
                "addDate":"2010-09-30 10:20:03"
            }
```

I can't loop this Json because don't have a key for the method-call .getJSONArray("key")

This is my java

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultValue);

    //JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("key");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
     JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     int products_id = objJson.getInt("products_id");
     String products_name = objJson.getString("products_name");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),products_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

Comment: iam not an expert, but my first call would be to check the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). I woul say the methode names() and get() of the JSONObject might help. But there seem to be many possibilities. :)

Comment: Proably JSONArray would be better [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.htmlml). I woul say the methode length() and get() of the JSONArray might help. :)

Comment: Thanks winner_joiner for help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your result contains a `JSONArray` with two indexes (0,1).
Run the loop twice or size of **JSONArray**. Get the value against the key `products_id`.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourStringData);
for(int i = 0; i<array.length() ; i++){
   String productInfo = array.get(i);

   JSONObject object = new JSONObject(productInfo );
   String myRequiredData = object.get("products_id");
 }
```

Comment: Fahad Ishaque thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize JSONArray, instead of JSONObject:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultValue); //resultValue is your string
```

after that, you can iterate through this array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
 ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, u've already answered it. My bad!

Comment: Thank that's works! Denamd you are hero for me!